# Async View in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Working on a django app that depends on a payment API, the app has to redirect based on response from user's phone input which takes a while, is there a way to use `async` to wait for the user's input before running the rest of the code.
I would like for the code to run only once it gets the `response` as shown in the function below.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
class CallBack(TemplateView):

template_name = 'callback.html'

def get(self, request):

    response = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    result_code = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["ResultCode"]
    
    if result_code == 0:
        merchant_request_id = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["MerchantRequestID"]
        checkout_request_id = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CheckoutRequestID"]
        result_code = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["ResultCode"]
        amount = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][0]["Value"]
        mpesa_receipt_number = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][1]["Value"]
        transaction_date = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][2]["Value"]
        phone_number = response["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"][3]["Value"]
        str_transaction_date = str(transaction_date)
        transaction_datetime = datetime.strptime(
            str_transaction_date, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        aware_transaction_datetime = pytz.utc.localize(
            transaction_datetime)
        
        our_model = Mpesa.objects.create(
            CheckoutRequestID=checkout_request_id,
            MerchantRequestID=merchant_request_id,
            PhoneNumber=phone_number,
            MpesaReceiptNumber=mpesa_receipt_number,
            Amount=amount,
            ResultCode=result_code,
            TransactionDate=aware_transaction_datetime,
        )
        our_model.save()
        
        return redirect('realtor:create')
    else:
        return redirect('payments:lipa_na_mpesa')
```

Comment: Where exactly are you waiting for user response? I can't see anything in your code that performs any waiting.

Comment: I want to wait on `response = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))`